# Java - split after number of characters?

Tags: java, string, split, char

I have a String and want to split it after a number of characters...

Example Code:

```
    //This is what I have:
    String text = "12345678";
    List<String> tmpListFirst = new LinkedList<>();
    List<String> tmpListSecond = new LinkedList<>();
    int splitAfter = 3; //split after the second character (this value is variable)

    //The result should look like this:
    tmpListFirst.get(0) //== 678
    tmpListFirst.get(0) //== 12345
```

Comment: Look at the [`Substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method of the `String` class

Comment: You said split after 3, but your output indicates that you want it split after 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String text = "12345678";
int splitAfter = 3;
List<String> tmpListFirst = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> tmpListSecond = new LinkedList<>();
tmpListFirst.add(text.substring(0, splitAfter));
tmpListSecond.add(text.substring(splitAfter));
```

That's if you want the values stored in a list. Otherwise they can really be stored in Strings just by doing `String s1 = text.substring(0, splitAfter);` and
`String s2 = text.substring(splitAfter);`

Comment: Nice answer. 1+ And an apology to your previous answer. The original poster did in fact want to display the graphic in a window, so sorry for the down-vote, it was wrongly placed.

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "12345678";
text = text.substring(0, 1) //will print 1
text = text.substring(3, text.length()) //will print 45678
text = text.substring(3) //will also print 45678
```

should be exactly what you're looking for. Will be much easier than using the String.split() method after n characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. this will give you exactly your desired results:

```
String text = "12345678";
List<String> tmpListFirst = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> tmpListSecond = new LinkedList<>();
int splitAfter = 5; //split after the second character (this value is variable)

//The result should look like this:
tmpListFirst.add(text.substring(splitAfter));//678
tmpListSecond.add(text.substring(0, splitAfter)); //== 12345

System.out.println(tmpListFirst.get(0));
System.out.println(tmpListSecond.get(0));
```

If you do not need to use List or LinkedList then the program will be very simple like:-

```
String text = "12345678";
int splitAfter = 5; //split after the second character (this value is variable)

System.out.println(text.substring(splitAfter)); //678
System.out.println(text.substring(0, splitAfter)); //12345
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right, you want to do smth like

```
String text = "12345678";
System.out.println(text.substring(0, 5));
System.out.println(text.substring(5));

//-----------output-------------
12345
678
```